# boost::interprocess::basic_string as std::string

Tags: c++, boost, stdstring, boost-interprocess

I am trying to replace a class method which returns **const std::string &** with **const boost::interprocess::basic_string &**. The main challenge I am facing is the incompatibility between the two classes despite their implementation similarity. For more clear explanation I will put that into code

```
class A
{ std::string m_str;
 const std::string & StrVal() { return m_str; }
}
```

Now this class has to look like this:

```
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<char,boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocatorChar;
typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,ShmemAllocatorChar> ShMemString;

class A
{
 ShMemString m_str;
 const ShMemString & StrVal() { return m_str; }
}
```

The problem is that we have a huge code base depending on this:

```
A a;
const std::string & str = a.StrVal();
// Many string specific operations go here, comparing str with other std::strings for instance
```

Even If I go over all the code replacing the expected results with const ShMemString &, it will be an even harder work to also fix the uses that follow. I was surprised to find out that the boost's string does not include any comparison/construction methods from std::string.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `boost::interprocess::basic_string<>` did have a conversion to `std::basic_string<>`, it would be completely useless for your purposes -- after the conversion, the interprocess string would be destroyed, and *its* allocator is the important one (i.e., the one holding the data in shared memory, which I assume is your motivation for switching `basic_string<>` implementations in the first place).

So, in the end, you have no choice but to go over all the code replacing the expected results with `ShMemString const&` (or `auto const&` if your compiler is recent enough to support it).

---

To make this less painful in the future, `typedef` judiciously:

```
struct A
{
    typedef ShMemString StrValType;
    StrValType const& StrVal() { return m_str; }
private:
    StrValType m_str;
};

// ...

A a;
A::StrValType const& str = a.StrVal();
```

This way, only the `typedef` inside of `A` needs to change and all code relying on it will automatically use the correct type.

Comment: So, how does this solve the problem of the missing comparison functions from `interprocess::string`?

Comment: @Nicol : Why should `boost::interprocess::string` have functions built-in to compare to `std::string`? What purpose would that serve other than to tightly couple the former to the latter? I.e., one can simply use any iterator-based algorithm and avoid the coupling.

Comment: That `interporcess::basic_string` shouldn't have comparison functions to `std::string` may be true. But saying it does not solve his problem. He still _needs_ those comparison functions in order to get done the things he needs to do. Your suggestion is basically to abandon `std::string` _everywhere_ in his codebase, even in places that aren't dealing with interprocess communication. That is an exceedingly heavyweight change, and there is no real need for it.

Comment: @Nicol : No, I'm advocating using iterator-based comparison algorithms instead of `boost::interprocess::string`/`std::string` member functions.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that we have a huge code base depending on this:

Why does `A::StrVal` in the second one return an `interprocess::basic_string`? It is an implementation detail of the class `A` that it uses `interprocess::basic_string` internally. The actual string class it's *interface* uses does not have to be the same. This is simply poor refactoring.

`A::StrVal` should return a `std::string`, just like always (well, not a `const&` of course, but user code won't need to change because of that). And therefore, `A::StrVal` will need to do the conversion between the two string types. That's how proper refactoring is done: you change the implementation, but the *interface* stays the same.

Yes, this means you're going to have to copy the string data. Live with it.

Comment: I don't think it's an implementation detail that the class intends to return data stored in shared memory...

Comment: @ildjarn: It is if the last version of the class returned a `std::string`. And if the interface needs to change, then it should still support the old `std::string` interface while supporting the new one too. You _never_ modify an existing interface when you refactor something. You can add new interfaces, but you still need to support the old ones.

Comment: I don't know what to say other than that I disagree almost completely.

Comment: @Nicol unfortunately keeping the interface and returning `std::string &` would involve keeping an additional member and synchronizing its value solely for the purpose of this method.

Comment: @Yordan: Who says that you would need to return a `std::string&`? Just return it by value. You return a `const std::string &` now, so even if they capture it by `const std::string &`, it will still work. The const& will extend the lifetime of the temporary.

Comment: @Nicol: I see your idea now, 10x I would consider this.